# Nginx - Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in

Tags: php, variables, pass-by-reference

i got this messages, when host in Nginx, it's just fine if i use Apache2

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO kategori VALUES (NULL, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", strtolower(trim($_POST['kategori'])));
if($stmt->execute()) {
    showAlert("Success add new category.", "success");
}
if (strpos($stmt->error,'Duplicate entry') !== false) showAlert("That category is already exist.");
```

what's wrong with that code? thanks

Comment: There are probably different PHP configurations for Apache HTTPD and nginx with different error reporting settings.